# mongoose schema wrong type

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this issue where i have defined a schema like this:

```
 analytics: {
    visits: {
      amounts: {
        type: Array,
        default: []
      },
      dates: {
        type: Array,
        default: []
      }
    },
  },
```

The problem is, when i take a look into the schema its not an array, it is `null`

```
 analytics: {
    visits: {
      amounts: null,
      dates: null
    },
  },
```

Why is it `null`

Comment: when you set `amounts` or `dates` to `null`, they will be `null` in the database. Is that what you ask?

Comment: @ĐăngKhoaĐinh no, thats not what i asked

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#arrays):

> specifying an empty array is equivalent to Mixed.

Try this:

```
analytics: {
    visits: {
      amounts: [],
      dates: []
    },
  },
```